# How to manage more than one dataset - Machine Learning Azure

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, data-transform

Is there any module that accepts more than one dataset for processing?
For instance "Split Data" , "Edit meta data" and "select columns in dataset" do not accept more than one dataset as input.

This is what I did :
There are several numeric and categorical variables in my model.I used "Convert to indicator variables " module to create dummy variables for my data.  How do I include the indicator variables and numeric variables into one dataset so that I can split the data for my model ?

As of now, I'm doing data wrangling in Python and moving the datasets in Azure MLS for modeling. Ideally, I need to work on data wrangling in Azure MLS.

I expect to have one module that consolidates both the categorical binned variables and numeric variables in Azure MLS

Answer (score 0):

Yup, there are several modules receiving multiple datasets - [Add Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/add-columns), [Apply SQL Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/apply-sql-transformation), [Execute Python Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/execute-python-script), to name a few.

Not sure why you need them for indicator values though - assuming you're talking about Train/Test Split, then I would just split the data after invoking the "Convert to indicator values" module.

Comment: I found the answer. I missed the overwrite categorical columns option in "Convert to indicator values".

Answer (score 0):

I will add to the above answer. You can use Execute R script,  Join data as well if the datasets have common keys.